# most likely due to a circular import (Como Resolver)

Tags: django, modelagem, referência-circular

Boa noite. Sou novo em Django/Python, estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde tenho um relacionamento circular, tenho a classe pessoa e a empresa, onde uma pessoa pertence a uma empresa e uma empresa é uma pessoa. Conforme as seguintes classes:

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    TIPO_CADASTRO_CHOICES = (
        (1, ('1. FUNCIONÁRIO')),
        (2, ('2. CLIENTE')),
        (3, ('3. FORNECEDOR')),
        (4, ('4. TRANSPORTADOR')),
    )

    TIPO_PESSOA_CHOICES = (
        (1, ('1. JURÍDICA')),
        (2, ('2. FISÍCA')),
    )

    nome = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )

    empresa = models.ForeignKey(
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        Empresa,
        null=True
    )

    tipo_cadastro = models.IntegerField(
        ('Tipo Cadastro'),
        choices=TIPO_CADASTRO_CHOICES,
        default=3
    )

    tipo_pessoa = models.IntegerField(
        ('Tipo Pessoa'),
        choices=TIPO_PESSOA_CHOICES,
        default=1
    )





class Empresa(models.Model):
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(
        Pessoa,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name='pessoa'
    )

    cnae= models.IntegerField(
        blank=True
    )

    corporacao = models.ForeignKey(
        Corporacao,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )




class Corporacao(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
```

Nesse cenário ao executar `makemigrations`, tenho o seguinte erro:

> File "D:\Desenv\Projetos\Python\neosis\apps\core\models\pessoa.py",
>   line 3, in from apps.core.models.empresas import Empresa File
>   "D:\Desenv\Projetos\Python\neosis\apps\core\models\empresas.py", line
>   5, in from .pessoa import Pessoa ImportError: cannot import name
>   'Pessoa' from partially initialized module 'apps.core.models.pessoa'
>   (most likely due to a circular import)

Como poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Estou querendo fazer o mesmo, mas fiquei com uma duvida na sua Classe Empresa, no seu caso uma empresa pode pertencer (se relaciona) a várias pessoas ? Desculpe se estiver muito equivocado, estou no início do aprendizado com Django.

Answer (score 2):

`Pessoa` está chamando `Empresa` que está sendo declarado logo embaixo, então como o código roda sequencialmente quando chegar em `Pessoa` a `Empresa` ainda não vai existir, pra resolver isso é bem simples basta apenas colocar em `string` o nome do modelo, veja a [documentação oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related) do django pra mais exemplos, eu particularmente prefiro ser um pouco mais explícito falando qual app e depois o model ao invés de somente falando o model.

```py
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    TIPO_CADASTRO_CHOICES = (
        (1, ('1. FUNCIONÁRIO')),
        (2, ('2. CLIENTE')),
        (3, ('3. FORNECEDOR')),
        (4, ('4. TRANSPORTADOR')),
    )

    TIPO_PESSOA_CHOICES = (
        (1, ('1. JURÍDICA')),
        (2, ('2. FISÍCA')),
    )

    nome = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )

    empresa = models.ForeignKey(
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        "Empresa",
        null=True
    )

    tipo_cadastro = models.IntegerField(
        ('Tipo Cadastro'),
        choices=TIPO_CADASTRO_CHOICES,
        default=3
    )

    tipo_pessoa = models.IntegerField(
        ('Tipo Pessoa'),
        choices=TIPO_PESSOA_CHOICES,
        default=1
    )





class Empresa(models.Model):
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(
        "Pessoa", # aqui não é mais necessário mas só pra manter o padrão
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name='pessoa'
    )

    cnae= models.IntegerField(
        blank=True
    )

    corporacao = models.ForeignKey(
        Corporacao,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )




class Corporacao(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
```